# How to use a dependsOn for the previous loop in Azure Devops YAML pipeline while using a each argument

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, yaml

I have a pipeline setup that is very basic and using the below template

```
parameters:
  - name: countries
    type: object
    default: 
    - country: 'uk'
      envs: ['development', 'preproduction', 'production']
    - country: 'us'
      envs: ['development', 'preproduction', 'production']

stages:
- ${{ each c in parameters.countries }}:
  - stage: ${{ c.country }}
    displayName: ${{ c.country }}
    # some variable here to control if to use [] to deploy to all stages or just one
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
    - ${{ each env in c.envs }}:
      - job: ${{ c.country }}_${{ env }}
        steps:
        - script: echo "Hello world"
          condition: contains(variables['System.JobDisplayName'], 'production')
        - script: echo "Hello world 2"
```

I want to have it so it only deploys to the new job loop in the pipeline if the previous job loop has succeeded. I can't seem to figure out a way of doing this. Any help will be appreicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this with the below job spec

```
- job: ${{ c.country }}_${{ env }}
        ${{if eq(env, 'preproduction')}}:
          condition: eq(dependencies.${{ c.country }}_development.result, 'Succeeded')
          dependsOn: ${{ c.country }}_development
        ${{if eq(env, 'production')}}:
          condition: eq(dependencies.${{ c.country }}_preproduction.result, 'Succeeded')
          dependsOn: ${{ c.country }}_preproduction
        steps:
```